# Can't get xml element's inner HTML using it's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have a large xml file with content like this:

```
<satellites>
<sat name="NSS 9/Yamal 300K (177.0W)" flags="0" position="-1770">
    <transponder frequency="3792000" symbol_rate="2048000" polarization="1" fec_inner="2" system="1" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="3987000" symbol_rate="8950000" polarization="1" fec_inner="2" system="0" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="3999000" symbol_rate="2960000" polarization="1" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4055000" symbol_rate="11000000" polarization="0" fec_inner="1" system="1" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4099000" symbol_rate="30000000" polarization="1" fec_inner="7" system="1" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4163000" symbol_rate="2644000" polarization="1" fec_inner="3" system="1" modulation="1"/>
</sat>
<sat name="AMC 8/18 (139.0W)" flags="0" position="-1390">
    <transponder frequency="4056000" symbol_rate="13250000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1"/>
</sat>
<sat name="AMC 10 (135.0W)" flags="0" position="-1350">
    <transponder frequency="3780000" symbol_rate="30000000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="1" modulation="2"/>
    <transponder frequency="3820000" symbol_rate="29270000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4080000" symbol_rate="29270000" polarization="1" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4136000" symbol_rate="19510000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4149000" symbol_rate="9760000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1"/>
    <transponder frequency="4180000" symbol_rate="29270000" polarization="0" fec_inner="5" system="0" modulation="1"/>
</sat>
</satellites>
```

I let the user choose the satellite, then I must get available frequencies for the chosen one. The first part I did, but now I can't get the `sat` element by it's `name` attribute to display transponder frequency list and other information.

This is my code: `var satellitesData = fileData.find('sat[name='+satName+']');`

Also tried this: `var satellitesData = $(fileData).find('sat[name='+satName+']');`

This: `var satellitesData = fileData.find('sat[name='+satName+'] > transponder');`

And this: `var satellitesData = fileData.find('sat[name='+satName+']').innerHTML;`

Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `name` attribute you're looking for often contains spaces, you need to enclose the searched attribute with quotes, otherwise the syntax will be invalid. Use `querySelector` rather than `.find` with standard Javascript (`.find` is for jQuery, or for plain Javascript arrays, but not for Javascript HTMLElements).

```js
const satName = "NSS 9/Yamal 300K (177.0W)";
const satellites = document.querySelector('satellites');
const satellitesData = satellites.querySelector('sat[name="' + satName + '"]');
console.log(satellitesData);
```

```html
<satellites>
  <sat name="NSS 9/Yamal 300K (177.0W)" flags="0" position="-1770">
    <transponder frequency="3792000" symbol_rate="2048000" polarization="1" fec_inner="2" system="1" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="3987000" symbol_rate="8950000" polarization="1" fec_inner="2" system="0" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="3999000" symbol_rate="2960000" polarization="1" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4055000" symbol_rate="11000000" polarization="0" fec_inner="1" system="1" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4099000" symbol_rate="30000000" polarization="1" fec_inner="7" system="1" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4163000" symbol_rate="2644000" polarization="1" fec_inner="3" system="1" modulation="1" />
  </sat>
  <sat name="AMC 8/18 (139.0W)" flags="0" position="-1390">
    <transponder frequency="4056000" symbol_rate="13250000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1" />
  </sat>
  <sat name="AMC 10 (135.0W)" flags="0" position="-1350">
    <transponder frequency="3780000" symbol_rate="30000000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="1" modulation="2" />
    <transponder frequency="3820000" symbol_rate="29270000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4080000" symbol_rate="29270000" polarization="1" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4136000" symbol_rate="19510000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4149000" symbol_rate="9760000" polarization="0" fec_inner="3" system="0" modulation="1" />
    <transponder frequency="4180000" symbol_rate="29270000" polarization="0" fec_inner="5" system="0" modulation="1" />
  </sat>
</satellites>
```

You might consider a template literal:

```
const satellitesData = satellites.querySelector(`sat[name="${satName}"]`);
```